# how can i remove stopwords in dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**this is my code and it doesn't work**

```
from pythainlp.corpus import thai_stopwords    
stopwords =thai_stopwords()
    def remove_stopwords(x):
      list_token = []
      for i in x:
          if i not in stopwords:
            list_token.append(i)

   return list_token
df['tokens']=df['tokens'].apply(remove_stopwords)
```

and i already try with this :

```
df['tokens'] = df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopwords])
```

Comment: What is your code meant to do? what is it doing instead? what is wrong with it? We are not on the same project with you. Take some time to read on how to ask a good question from this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `stopwords` is a list and `df['tokens']` is a list of words or tokens each.
Simple Method:

```
clear_tokens = []
for i in df.index:
   clear_tokens.append([item for item in df.tokens[i] if item not in stopwords])

df['tokens'] = clear_tokens
```

if your `df.tokens` is a sentence in each row, then :

```
clear_tokens = []
for i in df.index:
   tokenlist = df.tokens[i].split()
   clear_tokens.append(' '.join([item for item in tokenlist if item not in stopwords]))

df['tokens'] = clear_tokens
```